# Regex match everything except words between quotes

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to write a regex what matches everything except words between quotes. Ex.:

```
 Lorem ipsum "dolor" sit amet, consectetur "adipiscing" elit.
 Nunc ultrices varius odio, "ut accumsan nisi" aliquet vitae.
 "Ut faucibus augue tortor, at aliquam purus dignissim eget."
```

So I want a regex what matches the following strings:

- Lorem ipsum
- sit amet, consectetur
- elit. Nunc ultrices varius odio,
- aliquet vitae.

I only have the following expression that matches substrings inside quotes:

```
([\"'])(?:\\\1|.)*?\1
```

Comment: And what regex do you have currently?

Comment: I have this `([\"'])(?:\\\1|.)*?\1` , but I want the opposite. Everything what does not match for this.

Comment: Are you using PHP/PCRE? Try https://regex101.com/r/D1WE0g/1.

Comment: If you don't expect escaped quotes or single quotes, also try [`\G(?:"[^"]*"\K)?[^"]+`](https://regex101.com/r/mbgo5w/1)

Comment: Do our suggestions work?

Answer (score 2):

This regex works:

```
([^"]+?)(".*?"|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/um9TEx/3

```
1st Capturing Group ([^"]+?)
Match a single character not present in the list below [^"]+?
+? Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
" matches the character " literally (case sensitive)
" matches the character " literally (case sensitive)
.*? matches any character (except for line terminators)
*? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
" matches the character " literally (case sensitive)
```

Comment: But It doest match strings without qoutes.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PCRE, you may use

```
([\"'])(?:\\.|(?!\1)[^\\])*?\1(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:[^\\"']|\\.)+
```

See [its demo](https://regex101.com/r/D1WE0g/1).

**Details**

- `([\"'])(?:\\.|(?!\1)[^\\])*?\1` - a `"..."` or `'...'` substring with escaped quote support:

  - `([\"'])` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1`): a `"` or `'`
  - `(?:\\.|(?!\1)[^\\])*?` - 0+ occurrences (as few as possible due to `*?` being lazy) of:

    - `\\.` - an escape sequence
    - `|` - or
    - `(?!\1)[^\\]` - any char other than `\` and the quote char in Group 1
  - `\1` - Same value as in Group 1 (`"` or `'`)
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - PCRE verbs that omit the current match and make the engine proceed to the next match from the current match end position
- `|` - or
- `(?:[^\\"']|\\.)+` - 1 or more occurrences of:

  - `[^\\"']` - a char other than `\`, `'` or `"`
  - `\\.` - an escape sequence.

Comment: So anyone doesn't take forever to figure this part out everything before the | just discards everything inside quotes. I didn't even know you could discard matches with regex.