# Split R string at spaces but not when the space is between single quotes

Tags: r, regex

I have and ugly and complex set of strings that I have to split:

```
vec <- c("'01'", "'01' '02'", 
         "#bateau", "#bateau #batiment",
         "#'autres 32'", "#'autres 32' #'batiment 30'", "#'autres 32' #'batiment 30' #'contenu 31'",
         "#'34'", "#'34' #'33' #'35'")
vec
[1] "'01'"                                      "'01' '02'"                                
[3] "#bateau"                                   "#bateau #batiment"                        
[5] "#'autres 32'"                              "#'autres 32' #'batiment 30'"              
[7] "#'autres 32' #'batiment 30' #'contenu 31'" "#'34'"                                    
[9] "#'34' #'33' #'35'"
```

I need to split the string everywhere there is a space (), except if the space is between `'`.  So in the example above, `'01' '02'` would become `'01'` and `'02'` while `#'autres 32' #'batiment 30'` would become `#'autres 32'` and `#'batiment 30'`.

I've tried getting inspiration from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45811754/regex-match-everything-except-words-between-quotes), but didn't get far:

```
strsplit(vec, "(\\s[^']+?)('.*?'|$)")
```

as this solution split some spaces that shouldn't and make me loose some information as well.

The result from the split should be something like:

```
res <- c("'01'", "'01'", "'02'", 
         "#bateau", "#bateau", "#batiment",
         "#'autres 32'", "#'autres 32'", "#'batiment 30'", "#'autres 32'", "#'batiment 30'", "#'contenu 31'",
         "#'34'", "#'34'", "#'33'", "#'35'")
```

What would be the proper regular expression to split this string?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
strsplit(vec, "'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|\\s+", perl=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo](https://rextester.com/KYOHV49816) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SEa8PZ/1) online.

**Details**

- `'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)` - `'`, then any 0+ chars other than `'` (see `[^']*`) and then `'`, and then this matched text is discarded and the next match is searched for from the position where the current match got failed (see [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex))
- `|` - or
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars.

Since it is a PCRE pattern, the `perl=TRUE` is obligatory.